# How to get a client's Window size

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

So i am new to C# and Visual Basic.
I am trying to get a clients sizes. Basically i am trying to find a function that will return me the clients size either in an array either separately, x + y size.

I am not trying to get my desktops or my apps size. I am trying to do something like this:

```
var size = WinGetSize("RandomWindow");
```

and then play with the size.

Any help?

Comment: Windows Forms, WPF, Web Forms?

Comment: I am trying to get a windows form application. It's an .exe

Comment: You means you use c# to get a application/window's size? Or use winform to get it's own self?

Comment: As i am saying in the first post i dont want to get my app's size.
I am doing some math calculations and i want to get a client's size.
It is an window app .exe and i want to get it's size.

Comment: what is meant by `size` and `client` be more specific please

Comment: @chouaib: the OP means the size of some other window on the user's desktop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All right, you need win api,here is an example (code of c#):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("User32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindow")]
        public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]

        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]

        static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, ref RECT lpRect);

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]

        public struct RECT
        {

            public int Left; 

            public int Top; 

            public int Right; 

            public int Bottom; 

        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string WinTitle = ""; //windows title
            IntPtr awin = FindWindow(null, WinTitle);
            if (awin != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                RECT rc = new RECT();

                GetWindowRect(awin, ref rc);

                int width = rc.Right - rc.Left; 

                int height = rc.Bottom - rc.Top; 

                int x = rc.Left;

                int y = rc.Top;

                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("width:{0} height:{1} left:{2} top:{3}", width, height, x, y));
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("can not find the window");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice code, Good programming ... BUT please try not only code answers !

Comment: using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
I added this and tried exactly the way to posted and couldn't use DLLImport. I don't know why.
I tested it today and everything fine.

Thank you.